# Using a nested for loop to create a grid of rectangles in Pygame, why isn't it drawing correctly?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to create the grid of 5x5 rectangles from part 4 of the Pygame lab [here](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=lab_loopy_lab&lang=en). I've created my loop which seems to make logical sense, and the coordinates update correctly while debugging, but when it draws to the screen it comes out in a strange pattern like this:

[image]

Here is the loop I'm using:

```
for x in range(0, 100, 10):
    for y in range(0, 100, 10):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, [(x, y),(x + 5, y + 5)], 1)
```

I'm obviously doing something stupid here, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've made the width 1 to help with troubleshooting the issue, that will be removed once it's fixed to make the rectangles solid.

Comment: The size of a cell is (5, 5)  not (x+5, y+5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pygame rectangle is specified by the position and size. The size of the rectangle is always `(5, 5)` instead of  `(x + 5, y + 5)`:

<s>`pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, [(x, y),(x + 5, y + 5)], 1)`</s>

```py
pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, [(x, y), (5, 5)], 1)
```

Comment: Ahhh right, I was reading the documentation wrong. Thought you had to specify the x and y coordinates of the top left and bottom right corners. But I understand now, thanks :)